# Conditional Rendering in Lightning Component with more than Aura:If(True, ELSE)

Tags: rendered, conditional, lightning-inputfield, aura-if

I have a `lightning:select` picklist on a Lightning component called "Best Method of Contact" which is a required picklist, but the required picklist defaults to a blank 'placeholder' value that the user must change. The values are as follows:

- -SELECT ONE- (Default/Undefined)
- Phone
- Email

> **Issue:** I also want to present the user with a `lightning:input` to enter
>   either a Phone Number, or an Email, and I want this rendered
>   dynamically onChange of the picklist so that if the user chooses
>   "Email" they get the Email input, and the Phone input for Phone.
>
> However, when the user hasn't selected either option yet, and is still
>   set to the default -SELECT ONE- option, I don't want to render EITHER
>   of the `lightning:input` fields on the page.

I know `aura:if` is the lightning equivalent of `If X, Do Y, ELSE do Z` but it doesn't appear to have an ELSE IF condition in the documentation, so it really is only a boolean as far as I can tell. If the condition is met, render A, otherwise render B.

This doesn't work in my case because I have 3 conditions not 2, A (Phone), B (Email), and C (None).

> **Question:** I imagine I can wrap an `aura:if` around another `aura:if` to use it
>   very similarly to an IF statement in a Formula field, but before I
>   went down that route I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing any other
>   (better or more reliable) option that I might be able to use for this.
>   `Lightning:input` doesn't have a `rendered` variable like the
>   `apex:outputPanel` component does, so I can't set it there, and I
>   can't find an equivalent to the rendered variable on the `lightning:`
>   components
>
> Is there a more correct way to do this?

Comment: Why not just use 3 different `aura:if` blocks with different conditions? At any given point of time, you will only have one of those values.

Comment: because sometimes it takes someone elses brain to adapt for when yours stops working anymore ;) (I hadn't thought of that to be honest), a valid point. I guess I was too focused on using the aura:if along with its ELSE condition that I didn't consider that I could use it without it. I guess aura:if is the go-to options then yeah?

Comment: And sometimes you just have to live with what you get, and as you rightly figured out that there's no easy way for using an if, else, else-if here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would think the simplest way to achieve is to just write 3 different `aura:if` blocks. Something as below?

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.selectedVal == 'Phone'}">
    .. do something ..
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.selectedVal == 'Email'}">
    .. do something ..
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.selectedVal == 'None'}">
    .. do something ..
</aura:if>
```

Comment: +1 or, alternatively, nested aura:if.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to make sure there wasn't a different way to approach rendering in Lightning than this. In the end I suppose I only need 2 Aura:ifs since the third condition is just to have a blank area, but the answer works just the same.

Comment: @sfdcfox Just restricted myself to the most "simplest" approach :)

Comment: Totally works here, but sometimes you really want/need nested elements, so it's good to know that there's more than one possible way to do things. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use if, else-if, else with nested elements:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.selected == 'None'}">
  <aura:set attribute="else">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.selected == 'Phone'}">
      <lightning:input label="Phone" ... />
      <aura:set attribute="else">
        <lightning:input label="Email" ... />
      </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
  </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```